# Unable to generate wsdl file with methods having type generic collection Datatype.?

Tags: web-services, proxy, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have a web service which has a method with parameter of type Collection( of Byte).
When i try to generate the proxy using the wsdl command but the datatype gets converted to single dimensional Array of Bytes.

So i thought of creating the wsdl file which will have the type as Collection(of byte) using Add as Service Reference, but even though i specify collection type as Collection.objectModel still the parameter has the datatype as  single dimensional Array of Bytes.

Is there any way to do this, or manual do i need to change in the proxy file.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the collection type:

> svcutil /t:code 
>   /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1

[Full SvcUtil documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx).

Comment: I did try that by using Add Service Reference in Advanced option,
but still in wdsl the datatype is represented as
 <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="colTxnDocs" type="tns:ArrayOfBase64Binary" />

tns:ArrayOfBase64Binary so when proxy is created it is created as Array of Bytes instead of Collection(of Byte)

Comment: The WSDL will always show an ArrayOfWhatever, as generic types are not a concept that can be represented with XSD and WSDL. When you generate code from a WSDL, you can choose whether to generate arrays, List<T>, etc.

Comment: Looks like its by design in the case of webservice.

Answer (score 0):

I also have created a web service in which a method returns collection array of bytes. 
i am attaching sample code and its generated wsdl. Hope this may help you

```
public byte[][] GetPDFs(String searchQuery)
    {
List<Byte[]> list = new List<byte[]>();
// DO YOUR WORK
 return list.ToArray();
}
```

and genetated `wsdl:type` in wsdl is

```
    <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://TDS.elixir.com/">
      <s:element name="GetPDFs">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="searchQuery" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>

      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetPDFsResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetPDFsResult" type="tns:ArrayOfBase64Binary" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="ArrayOfBase64Binary">

        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="s:base64Binary" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
```

and generated proxy code (wsdl.exe or by using add reference) is like:

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/GetPDFs", RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public byte[][] GetPDFs(string searchQuery) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("GetPDFs", new object[] {
                    searchQuery});
        return ((byte[][])(results[0]));
    }
```

Please let me know if you need further help.